# selenium webdriver unable to find element from its xpath even though the xpath is correct

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to get the attributes of a tag using selenium webdriver and using the xpath as a locator. I gave the xpath to the driver and it returned `NoSuchElementException`, but when I enter the xpath in the "Inspect element" window, it showed that particular tag, which means the locator does exist. So what's wrong with selenium? Its still the same even if I give the full xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://cq-portal.webomates.com/#/login')


element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
print(element.get_attribute('class'))

driver.quit()
```

selenium version = 3.141.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just give wait to load the page. Your code is perfectly fine. Either give hardcode wait like sleep or presence of element. Both will work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://cq-portal.webomates.com/#/login')

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button']")))

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button']")
print(element.get_attribute('class'))

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block

Answer (score 0):

Loops like you are missing a delay.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://cq-portal.webomates.com/#/login')

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button']")))

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
print(element.get_attribute('class'))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried running this code but this time I got a TimeoutException error with a weird backtrace

Comment: @BibekjitSingh You are right. The above code wouldn't work because the button is initially in disabled state, and here, we are checking "visibility_of_element_located". Thats why, you are getting Timeout exception with weird stacktrace.

Comment: @QualityMatters good catch, man!